# Can Windows 10 IoT run MFC Applications

Tags: mfc, windows-10-iot-core

I have a program I am trying to gut the UI from and just let it manipulate data and store it on a harddrive.  The program is written using MFC.  Can windows 10 IoT run MFC applications?

Answer (score 2):

There are [two editions of Windows 10 IoT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/windows-iot): Windows 10 IoT core and Windows 10 IoT Enterprise.

Windows 10 IoT Core is a mini version of Windows 10 that is optimized for smaller devices. Its mainly supported app type is UWP and there is some limitation of the traditional Win32 app because there is no Win32 UI stack on IoT Core. More information is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore).

Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is a full version of Windows 10 that delivers enterprise manageability and security to IoT solutions.

For your use case, you can choose Windows 10 IoT Enterprise.

Comment: Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is a paid license and not a free download so that may be a criteria the OP should consider.